# Update Password flow

Tags: security

I implementing an update password feature.
I want to let the user change his password. To be able to do that, the user should enter the old password and the new password (with confirmation).

I am not sure about how to handle the case when the user enters the wrong old password. I have 2 options in my mind:

1. Logout the user
2. Do not the operation and return an error

Option 1 prevents me from a situation when the user is not a legit user but for a worse experience user.
Option 2 provides a better user experience obviously because in that case, the user doesn't need to re-login him if he makes a typo error.

What do you think?

Comment: I'd go for 2 any time as long as the system does not shoot missiles.

Answer (score 0):

I would not sign the user out if they typed their password in incorrectly. There is a high possibility that a user could make a typo when entering their password. It is also not common practice to log a user out for making a mistake while using a program. However, it is a security concern for an unauthorized user that has somehow managed to access someone else's account to be allowed to make unlimited attempts to change their password.

I see two possible solutions, but I would not log the user out if they typed their password incorrectly.

- First, you could limit the number of attempts that a user could try to enter their password to a reasonable number like 5-10. After a set number of attempts, you could prevent the user from resetting their password for 24 hours.
- Second, you could enable some form of two factor authentication for a password reset. This is common practice for many companies. This may not be possible in your situation, but this is likely the most secure and least intrusive solution.

If you are worried about security, it would also be important to notify the user that their account may have been compromised.